# How to use a Qt 4 plugin or self developed plugin in qt application?

Tags: qt4, linker, external, libs

I'm trying to make a simple application for calendar and it doesn't seem to link properly.
Platform: WinXP, Qt: 4.5.3 with MinGW

The application is trying to use a predeveloped qt plugin "worldtimeclockplugin" from C:\Qt\4.5.3\plugins\designer. I dragged and dropped this widget in Qt designer on a dialog and then tried to build the app.

I tried all possible ways mentioned in Qmake documention and forums, but the linker doesn't find the library and fails to link the application.

Can someone provide me the right clues?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are doing, the plugin you mention is designed so that Qt Designer knows about the widget.  It isn't designed to interact with the actual program so developed.  In those situations, you need to either create a separate plugin for use by those applications, or compile the source code directly into your application.